# IOControlCode asks for UShort, but ours is DWORD

Tags: c#, driver, windows-10, win-universal-app, deviceiocontrol

I am creating a Custom Device for Universal Apps in Windows 10. Our previous app (runs for XP, 7, and 8 without Universal) has been using Driver control codes as a `DWORD`, but the `Windows.Devices.Custom` Namespace uses a function `IOControlCode()` uses ushort.

The function we used to use is:

```
DeviceIoControl(HANDLE, DWORD, void*, DWORD,
            void*, DWORD, DWORD, NULL);
```

See the new documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.custom.iocontrolcode.iocontrolcode.aspx)

Is there any alternative or way around this?

Comment: Are you sure its ushort? Looks like uint to me: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.custom.iocontrolcode.controlcode.aspx Do you have a link to the API that uses ulong?

Comment: I think it uses `uint` not `ushort` but that would be still only 32bits not 64 like for `ulong`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IOControlCode() parameters are function and device type. These make up an IOControlCode, and are correctly assign UShorts.

The DeviceIOControl function I posted was not the one I should have been looking at. The equivalent function is actually

## define IOCTL_CTL_CODE(code) CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, code|0x0100, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_ANY_ACCESS)

Where File_Device_Unknown is given in the DDK as 0x00000022 and code|0x0100 is the function.